# Prevent onclick when ondblclick is triggered

Tags: events, jsf, ajax4jsf

stackoverflow world!

I have h:panelGrid, containing some elements.

I want to trigger an action when user clicks it and I want to trigger another action when use double clicks it.

I have the following code now:

```
<h:panelGrid ...>
  <a4j:support event="ondblclick" actionListener="#{page.doubleClicked}"/>
  <a4j:support event="onclick" actionListener="#{page.clicked}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

So the result...
When I click it, I got what I need.
But when I double click it, I got three calls: click, click and then doubleclick.

So the question is: how to prevent two click calls when we have a doubleclick?

I need both actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://community.jboss.org/message/62874?tstart=-1